# How to make the changes made to the model effective with DataBinding after setModel?

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, binding, datamodel

DataBinding: how can I make sure that as a result of a modification of the data model the view is updated accordingly?
Eg:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MyActivityBinding mBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.my_activity);
      mBinding.setMyModel(new MyModel());
    }

    public void onClickAnItem(View view) {
      MyModel model = mBinding.getMyModel();
      model.setField1 = "Jhon";
      model.setField2 = "Dho";
      mBinding.executePendingBindings();
    }
}
```

In this case the model "MyModel" has been modified but view is not updated; what did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading documentation I found a solution, first of all:
Any plain old Java object (POJO) may be used for data binding, but modifying a POJO will not cause the UI to update!
To give MyModel data object the ability to notify when data changes I made this modifications:

```
private class MyModel extends BaseObservable {
   private String field1;
   private String field2;

   @Bindable
   public String getField1() {
       return this.field1;
   }
   @Bindable
   public String getField2() {
       return this.field2;
   }
   public void setField1(String firstName) {
       this.field1 = firstName;
       notifyPropertyChanged(BR.field1);
   }
   public void setField2(String lastName) {
       this.field2 = lastName;
       notifyPropertyChanged(BR.field2);
   }
}
```

I hope this can help someone else
[Documentation here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)